# How to optimize convex hull drawing?

Tags: python, opencv, optimization, convex-hull

I'm trying to archive drawing convex hull points based on area of cover (see first image below) in some input image (second image below). For this operation, I'm doing the following:

1. Find the contours in first image.
2. Find the contours in second image.
3. For every contours area in first image, compare with all contours in second image and check if they are inside of contour in first image. If it's inside of contour area, append `x, y` coordinates of contour to list.
4. Draw convex hull points in list.

My problem is that step 3 is taking too much time, because of comparing every contour in the second image. Is there any way to optimize this code ?

```py
for coverContour in coverContours:
    try:
        points_ = []
        for pointsContour in pointsContours:

            ((x, y), r) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(pointsContour)

            if (cv2.pointPolygonTest(coverContour, (int(x), int(y)), False)) == 1:
                point_list.append((int(x), int(y)))
                points_.append(Point(int(x), int(y)))

        draw_point = Point.convex_hull(points_, len(points_))
        for x in range(len(draw_point)-1):
            cv2.line(layer, (points_[draw_point[x]].x, points_[draw_point[x]].y),
                     (points_[draw_point[x+1]].x, points_[draw_point[x+1]].y), (255, 255, 255), line_thickness)

        cv2.line(layer, (points_[draw_point[len(draw_point)-1]].x, points_[draw_point[len(draw_point)-1]].y),
                 (points_[draw_point[0]].x, points_[draw_point[0]].y), (255, 255, 255), line_thickness)
    except:
        print('')
```

Cover image:

[image: Cover Image]

Input image:

[image: Input Image]

Final image:

[image: final image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested your code, since it's missing parts to run it out-of-the-box, so I don't know, how to quantify *taking too much time* here. The below mentioned approach takes around 50 ms on my machine (i7 3.60 GHz, 32 GB RAM). If that's worthy, please continue reading. ;-)

That'd be my final output:

[image: Output]

1. Find all the "blob" contours from the first image.
2. Iterate the "blob" contours, and draw each on a separate black background, cf. [`cv2.drawContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc).
3. Bitwise and (intersect) this image with the "details" from the second image.
4. Find all "details" contours within that intersection.
5. Simply concatenate all coordinates from the "details" contours, and call [`cv2.convexHull`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga014b28e56cb8854c0de4a211cb2be656).
6. Draw the convex hull on some output image.

That'd be the full code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read input images
blobs = cv2.imread('6Sh0t.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
details = cv2.imread('RdKkN.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Find blob contours w.r.t. the OpenCV version
cnt_blobs = cv2.findContours(blobs, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt_blobs = cnt_blobs[0] if len(cnt_blobs) == 2 else cnt_blobs[1]

# Prepare output image
output = np.zeros_like(blobs)

# Iterate all blob contours
for cnt in cnt_blobs:

    # Draw blob contour on empty, black background
    tmp = np.zeros_like(blobs)
    tmp = cv2.drawContours(tmp, [cnt], -1, 255, cv2.FILLED)

    # Bitwise and (intersection) blob contour with details
    tmp = cv2.bitwise_and(tmp, details)

    # Find details contours within intersection w.r.t. the OpenCV version
    cnts = cv2.findContours(tmp, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

    # Concatenate all coordinates, and get convex hull
    cnts = np.concatenate(cnts, axis=0)
    cnts = cv2.convexHull(cnts)

    # Draw in output
    output = cv2.drawContours(output, [cnts], -1, 128, 3)

# Output
cv2.imshow('Output', output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.8.5
NumPy:         1.19.5
OpenCV:        4.5.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: let me ask you one more question. Is there any easy way to draw a line to each point(contour) in same blob area ? (I'm trying to connect each point to others points in same blob area)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand your follow-up question. Maybe, [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) describing your problem in detail there, and maybe referencing to here for further context.